# Ubuntu 12.04 network issues

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, virtualbox

I have two network devices on my virtualbox with ubuntu server 12.04. I get this when I start up:

Starting configure network device [fail]

Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration.

I have added the second on in the: /etc/networks/interfaces

[image: enter image This is in the file:]

And I cant find the second one in the ifconfig:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first delete your 70-persistent-net file and shutdown your virtual machine after that refresh the MAC address, then again start the machine.

Again you have to edit the interface file, then start the networking service it will work